# Connecting to remote domino/lotus notes server to send/retrieve user mails, contacts, etc using C#

Tags: c#, api, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am trying to create a web service using C#/.Net that can remotely access any user's lotus notes mailbox, contacts, etc. That is given the sever address and username/password details I want to send mails, create contacts, etc. Much like what one might do with EWS managed API for exchange accounts. I am currently using interop.domino.dll for this. It hasn't worked for me so far.

```
var session = new NotesSession();
session.InitializeUsingNotesUserName("username", "password");
var db = session.GetDatabase( "server", "xyz.nsf", false );
```

throws exception saying "user is not a server" or

> "Failed to read server configuration"

I am a total lotus newbie and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have You tried var session = NotesSession.CreateSession("Lotus.NotesSession")? _this is highly experimental_

Comment: or replace xyz.nsf with full path?

Comment: "User is not a server" sounds like you may have passed the name of the Domino server in for the username argument to InitializeUsingNotesUserName.  Either that it's an ACL issue in the xyz.nsf database caused by identifying a group as a Server Group instead of Person Group or a Mixed group. As for the other error message, I'm not entirely sure.  What do you have installed on your local machine? Lotus Notes client software or Lotus Domino server software?

Comment: I also have to add this, with no disprespect intended: a project of the scope you just described is awfully ambitious for someone who is a "total newbie" to Lotus. Also, C# and .NET would not be my choice for an implementation environment for this because IBM does not support the interop code on a 64 bit OS. It can mostly be made to work, but there are known problems with some of the methods, and if you do run into anything that doesn't work, you're on your own.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I have Lotus Notes Client installed on my local machine. I want to talk to a remote domino server though. Also I do see what you mean about .NET not being the right environment for this but I need to add the notes integration to an already existing web service written entirely using .NET so I have to make some compromises.

Comment: @ntohl I tried both things. Same outcome.

Comment: You may want to consider the Domino REST API instead of the COM API. I'm on my phone now, so I can't really get you any links, but IBM seems to be calling it the Domino Access Services API now and it was formerly known as Domino Data Services, so searching on those terms should get you to where you need to learn about it. The downsides are that it only works for versions of Domino released in the past 4 or 5 years and it does require some admin to set up on the servers. But it's supported. If I were doing a .Net integration project, I'd give it serious consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed the server and client way to access the NotesSession. You have two choices:

1. Client Way

   `session.Initialize("password");` or `session.Initialize();`

   Install a Notes Client and use `Initialize()`. If the client is started you do not need to provide a password. If the client is not started a password query will appear. The client is using the configured notes.id and needs that password. You could create a superuser id, that is capable to access all mail file and you do the authentication on your own. [Initialize (NotesSession - LotusScript®)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_INITIALIZE_METHOD_SESSION_COM.html)

   This also should work on a server, but never tried this.
2. Server Way

   `session.InitializeUsingNotesUserName("username", "password");`

   I never tried this, but mistakenly used the method, so I know it's an error to use it with a client.

   Theoretically: You Install a Domino Server and use the username and http-password of a user to identify as this user. I don't know if the dll find the right installation if you mix Notes Client and Server on on computer. Theoretically this could be controlled by the path variable, which executables the dll can reach via path. [InitializeUsingNotesUserName (NotesSession - LotusScript®)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_INITIALIZEUSINGNOTESUSERNAME_METHOD_SESSION_COM.html)

   Domino Server on Windows Client: You can install a Domino Server on a Windows Client for testing purposes, the server will have limited network connections, because of the windows client, but it's utilizable for development. Bear in mind the EULA for Microsoft and IBM.

interop.domino.dll is not in focus of IBM any more. So think about what Richard Schwartz said and focus on the existing REST API or write your own web services as Notes Database and access it from C# as web service.

Comment: I tried the following with my Notes Client running
         var session = new NotesSessionClass();
         session.Initialize();
And got the same exception again:
        User *** is not a server

Comment: @cookiemonster Strange. Do you have a client an server on your machine installed? In [this post by Carl Tyler](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/881cbda7bcfc0a0585257937005e8831?OpenDocument) he is guessing that COM uses the interface from the last installed instance (Client or Server)

Comment: @cookiemonster Another idea, take a look at your local notes.ini and check if [KitType=1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21216611) what means workstation.

Comment: Okay so I just have a Lotus Notes client installed here. I checked the local notes.ini too. It says KitType is 1.